# How to add Icons/Images for each Items in List View When data is coming from database in C#?

Tags: c#, database, listview

My Code:

```
SqlCommand cmdview = new SqlCommand("select * from menu_items_categories", s);
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adpt.SelectCommand = cmdview;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
adpt.Fill(dt);
 foreach (DataRow myrow in dt.Rows)
 {
 listView2.Items.Add(myrow[1].ToString())…
 }
```

This Code is running fine. All the items displaying in a list view when i chose View option = List. But when i chose View = LargeIcons items display fine but i want to display icons separately for each items.
How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the images?  In the database or are they already in the ImageList?

Comment: You seem to assume that items retrieved from a dbase should naturally map to an image or icon.  Could happen, technically it is possible to store an image into the dbase.  Doesn't typically make the dbase administrator very happy.  The more common case is that you keep images in your own program.  Mapping a dbase item to an image is now entirely up to you.  You have to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

use the ImageIndex property of the ListViewItem and bind an ImageList containing some images to your ListView.

Comment: Can you define me in detail please. Some code from you will hekp me.